# How to insert Row in SQL only If the records are not existed with the given time Date

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert data into SQL table – basically it has only 2 columns , I should only insert if the records are not existed within same Date
AND If the records are already existed with the same Date, then I should only Update do not insertion.

I wrote below stored proc – It works fine, however I noticed it is still inserting duplicate records in SQL if the input the SP has duplicate rows , so how do I avoid duplicate rows insertion into my table
I should only allow one row not the duplicate data for the same Date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddOrUpdateRecords]      
    @DataTableType AS dbo.Bil_Type READONLY       
AS    
BEGIN    
  SET NOCOUNT ON;   
   
MERGE [Bil_Outbound] AS target  
USING @DataTableType AS source  
    ON   
     Convert(date, target.CreatedDate) = Convert(date, getdate())  
    AND target.IncorrectNumber = source.IncorrectNumber   
WHEN MATCHED  THEN   
    UPDATE SET target.CorrectNumber = source.CorrectNumber,target.CreatedDate = getdate()  
         
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT (IncorrectNumber, CorrectNumber, CreatedDate)  
    VALUES (source.IncorrectNumber, source.CorrectNumber, Getdate());  
  
END
```

This is my Table Type

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Bil_Type AS TABLE(
    [IncorrectNumber]      VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    [CorrectNumber]           VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
);
```

Sample Data to the SP :-

```
IncorrectNumber CorrectNumber
2345543316  9990992595
3345513333  9805982192
4345513333  9800318871
5345513333  9800317654
2345543316  9990992595
4345513333  9800318871
```

Here 1st , 3rd are duplicate rows so it should only insert 1 row only.

Results in table should be like below :-

```
IncorrectNumber CorrectNumber
2345543316  9990992595
3345513333  9805982192
4345513333  9800318871
5345513333  9800317654
```

Comment: I would build a step to run to remove dupes on your data table that is passed to the SP before you run the merge statement.

Comment: You can use a CTE as source of the merge, which would allow you to filter out duplicates with help of ROW_NUMBER or other means

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to implement to remove the dedups in DataTable itself